# Ordering Choices in ModelForm ManytoManyField DJANGO

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have in my models.py

```
class Business(models.Model):
   industry = models.models.ManyToManyField(Industry)
```

in forms.py

```
class BusinessForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Business
```

When I render the form, the industry names appear in a multiple select box. What do I do to make the industry names in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There are several ways:

You can override the queryset ordering on a per-form basis, set the ordering meta class option, or override the model manager queryset with an ordering method.

#### Override global model manager queryset

```
class IndustryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return (
            super(IndustryManager, self)
            .get_query_set()
            .order_by('name')
        )

class Industry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    objects = IndustryManager()
```

#### Specify global meta option ordering

```
class Industry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```

#### Per form ordering

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Business

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)   
        self.fields['industry'].queryset = Industry.objects.order_by('name')
```

There's also a shortcut called formfield_for_manytomany if you are dealing with the django admin.

Comment: great answer, thank you very much! I also tried overriding all() method, but it didn't work. I went with overriding get_query_set. Works like a charm :)

Comment: Override what `all()` method? I don't think one exists, outside of the model Manager.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was frustrating me for a while

Comment: I would like to add that it might be more appropriate to directly get the queryset from the field itself: self.fields['industry'].queryset.order_by('name'). (Given that it concerns a relation field) Otherwise, you duplicated the class of the relation which is edited through this field.

Answer (score 2):

I like this method:

```
class BusinessForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Business

    industry = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
               queryset=Industry.objects.order_by('name'))
```

I like it, since it does not alter the database model, and since it is declarative (less programming).