# django admin sort foreign key field list

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, foreign-keys, django-admin

Is there an option in the django admin view for ordering of foreign key fields? i.e. I have a foreign key to a "School" model, which shows as a dropdown, sorted on pk-- I would like it to be sorted alphabetically.

Comment: I suppose you're looking for this:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923799/reorder-users-in-django-auth][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923799/reorder-users-in-django-auth

Answer (score 80, accepted):

[`ModelAdmin` specific ordering via `formfield_for_foreignkey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "school":
            kwargs["queryset"] = School.objects.order_by('name')
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Examples for 3 other non-admin-specific methods:

- [Set default global ordering via a Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541477/ordering-choices-in-modelform-manytomanyfield-django/6541738#6541738)
- [Set default ordering via model meta class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541477/ordering-choices-in-modelform-manytomanyfield-django/6541738#6541738)
- [Form specific ordering then passed to your ModelAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541477/ordering-choices-in-modelform-manytomanyfield-django/6541738#6541738)

Comment: This works for inlines too! And note that the parameters of `super` are not necessary in Python3.

Answer (score 8):

It seems to work to add an admin class to the model admin, with the ordering equal to the field you want the drop down list sorted by.

```
# in the admin.py file

class SchoolAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['school_name']

admin.site.register(SchoolModel, SchoolAdmin)
```

This works if you are willing to have an edit/add option next to drop down list.

Comment: A very simple and compact alternative is `admin.site.register(SchoolModel, ordering=['school_name'])` (working in django 3.1.5)

Answer (score 3):

The approved answer might override other changes on the queryset, so I prefer to use this because it's safer:

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_field_queryset(self, db, db_field, request):
        queryset = super().get_field_queryset(db, db_field, request)
        if db_field.name == 'school':
            queryset = queryset.order_by('name')
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override [**formfield_for_foreignkey()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) to change order as shown below:

```py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        formfield = super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == "school":            
            formfield.queryset = School.objects.order_by('name')
        return formfield
```