# How to alphabetically order a drop-down list in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, sorting

Here's a (very) simplified version of my models:

**laboratory/models.py**

```
class Lab(Model):
    professor = ForeignKey('authors.Author')
```

**authors/models.py**

```
class Author(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)
```

In the Django admin, when I add or update a Lab, a drop-down list containing each professors is automatically generated and displayed. The problem is this list is very long and it is not alphabetically ordered. I want the professor drop-down list to be alphabetically ordered by "name" field.

How can I do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992865/django-admin-sort-foreign-key-field-list

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can define default ordering for Author model:

```
class Author(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
```

Keep in mind that this causes the objects in Django also to ordered and migration will have to be done.

You can do `ordering = ['name']` under the AuthorAdmin file to order only for admin dashboard.

Comment: That was not the question, and has undesired side effects. This means that the objects are *always* ordered, not just in the admin panel.

Comment: IMHO its better not to set the ordering on model because the ordering of your admin page needs to be decoupled from the model

Answer (score 29):

[ModelAdmin specific ordering via formfield_for_foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey)

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "author":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Author.objects.filter(anyfilters=anyfilters).order_by('name')
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

**Note** IMHO its better not to set the ordering on `model` because the ordering of your admin page needs to be decoupled from the model.

Also all the queries fired on the model will use the `order_by` column, in which case you might have to index the ordering column with your other columns.

Comment: I agree with @ravi404. It's nice to be able to keep ordering separate in case it needs to be different in models.py than admin.py. This answer worked for me. I changed the queryset to include the ordering; something like: `kwargs['queryset'] = Car.objects.all().order_by('make')`.

Answer (score 8):

The current way to do this (January 2019):

In your admin.py file:

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['name']
```

And then register it:

```
admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
```

As described in the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.ordering

Answer (score -2):

Well, you can use the [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.ordering) variable in django admin, or you could use [`order_with_respect_to` underneath `class Meta`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.order_with_respect_to). So, first you need to add an `admin.py` file to the same directory as your `models.py` file. This is what your `admin.py` file should look like:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from models import Lab

class LabAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('name',)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name'] # ['-name'] if you want the opposite ordering


admin.site.register(Lab, LabAdmin)
```

Comment: This doesn't work - the `Meta` `ordering` option you're describing only works on the Model itself, not the `ModelAdmin` class.

Comment: "ordering" for ModelAdmin needs to be put under the class itself, not under Meta.